# What does this result of calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n$ mean?

Tags: matrices

Suppose a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
a & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. I need to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n$, so I started doing literally power by power to see a pattern, and this pattern emerges:

$$A^{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}
(A^n_{1,1}+A^n_{1,2})a & A^n_{1,1}b \\
(A^n_{2,1}+A^n_{2,2})a & A^n_{2,1}b
\end{pmatrix}$$

At $n=\infty$ supposedly $n=n+1$ so I define $\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
z & t
\end{pmatrix}$ as $A^n=A^{n+1}$

so we have that

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
z & t
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
(x+y)a & xb \\
(z+t)a & zb
\end{pmatrix}
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
(x+y)a &= x\\ 
xb&=y \\ 
(z+t)a &= z \\ 
zb&=t
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

simplifying we get to

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
b+1&=\frac 1a\\
ab+a&=1
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

Isolating $b$ in the first we have that $b=\frac 1a-1$; substituting on the second:

\begin{align}
a(1/a-1)+a&=1 \\
1-a+a=1 \\
1=1
\end{align}

The problem is I don't understand the result. Does this mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n$ is defined no matter what values $a$ and $b$ we have? What does it mean?

Comment: @Moo They are integers so they have two posible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B:=\lim_{n \to \infty}A^n$ if this limit exists. You noted that such a limit must satisfy $BA=B$, so after some calculations you found $b+1=1/a$. Thus the limit can only exist if $a$ and $b$ satisfy that equation.

You said $a$ and $b$ are integers, and there are two solutions to $b+1=1/a$. In the one case you can calculate $A^2$ and recognize what will happen as you take higher powers of $A$. In the second case, you can look at the determinant of $A$ and note that $\text{det}(A^n)=\text{det}(A)^n$, which will tell you something about whether or not $B$ can exist.